# Mix vertical and horizontal PanedWindow() on tkinter and moves sashes together

Tags: python, tkinter

I just started using `tkinter` and I am feeling good about it, but I am now facing an issue and can't seem to find anything about it. I am currently trying to create this shape with `PanedWindow():`

```
########|#######
#       |      #
--------|-------
#       |      #
########|#######
```

I currently have a code that does create this shape and I can resize the pane windows `(- & |)`. The problem is that I need these `(|)` to move together like these `(-)`. If that wasn't clear, I am trying to move the center dividers together. Currently, they are like so :

```
###|############
#  |           #
----------------
#           |  #
############|###
```

If this is still not clear, try it out! I put the code below. As you can see, you can move the vertical lines together, but not the horizontal ones. I know that the reason is that there are 2 independent pane windows inside of one main pane window, so they act independently. I still don't know how I could link them together!

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

master.geometry("400x400")

# Main Pane
main_panel = PanedWindow(orient=VERTICAL, bd=2, relief="solid", bg="black")
main_panel.pack(fill="both", expand=1)


# Sub Panes

##############################################################################

top_left = PanedWindow(main_panel, bd=1, relief="solid", bg="black")
top_left.pack(fill="both", expand=1)

left_label = Label(top_left, text= "Left-top")
top_left.add(left_label)

top_right = PanedWindow(top_left, orient=VERTICAL, bd=4)
top_left.add(top_right)

right_label = Label(top_left, text= "Right-top")
top_right.add(right_label)


#############################################################



bottom_left = PanedWindow(main_panel, bd=1, relief="solid", bg="black")
bottom_left.pack(fill="both", expand=1)

left_label = Label(bottom_left, text= "Left-bottom")
bottom_left.add(left_label)

bottom_right = PanedWindow(bottom_left, orient=VERTICAL, bd=4)
bottom_left.add(bottom_right)

right_label = Label(bottom_left, text= "Right-bottom")
bottom_right.add(right_label)


main_panel.add(top_left)
main_panel.add(bottom_left)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Your picture diagram shows four panes: a top and a bottom pane, and each of those seems to have a left and right pane. However, the code you've posted creates  five paned windows  when you only need three total. It would help if you reduced the code down to match the description of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to find a most general solution to this problem, as I thought you may want to add more paned windows to main_panel. Anyway this can be achieved with fewer lines of code, but for demonstration I did it more steps than needed.

References:

- [Level of bindings](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/binding-levels.html)
- [Methods for PanedWindow](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/panedwindow.html)
- [event objects](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/event-handlers.html)
- [universal widget methods](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html)

```
import tkinter as tk #dont use wildcard imports



def onB1Motion(event):#bindings are executed with event objects
    widget = event.widget #get widget/paned window of event
    x,y = event.x,event.y #get x and y coord of event
    data = widget.identify(x,y) #paned window identify
    if data != '': #identify returns empty string if child window
        idx = data[0] #get sash index
        orient = event.widget['orient'] #check for orientation of paned window
        for child in widget.master.winfo_children(): #get all children of master
            if isinstance(child,tk.PanedWindow): #if children is paned window do..
                if child['orient'] == orient: #if child paned window is same orient as event paned do..
                    child.sash_place(idx,x,y) #places the sash with same index on same position

LABEL_WIDTH = 10 #simulate natural size by label width

master = tk.Tk()
master.geometry("400x400")
# Main Pane
main_panel = tk.PanedWindow(orient=tk.VERTICAL, bd=2, relief="solid", bg="black")
main_panel.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
# Sub Panes
##############################################################################
top_left = tk.PanedWindow(main_panel, bd=1, relief="solid", bg="black")
top_left.pack(fill="both", expand=1)

left_label = tk.Label(top_left,width=LABEL_WIDTH, text= "Left-top")
top_left.add(left_label)

top_right = tk.PanedWindow(top_left, orient=tk.VERTICAL, bd=4)
top_left.add(top_right)

right_label = tk.Label(top_left,width=LABEL_WIDTH, text= "Right-top")
top_right.add(right_label)
##############################################################################
bottom_left = tk.PanedWindow(main_panel, bd=1, relief="solid", bg="black")
bottom_left.pack(fill="both", expand=1)

left_label = tk.Label(bottom_left,width=LABEL_WIDTH, text= "Left-bottom")
bottom_left.add(left_label)

bottom_right = tk.PanedWindow(bottom_left, orient=tk.VERTICAL, bd=4)
bottom_left.add(bottom_right)

right_label = tk.Label(bottom_left,width=LABEL_WIDTH, text= "Right-bottom")
bottom_right.add(right_label)
##############################################################################
main_panel.add(top_left)
main_panel.add(bottom_left)

##binding class/all paned windows to execute command {onB1Motion} by {B1-Motion}
## USE ADD=+ TO DONT OVERWRITE THE STANDARD ONE
master.bind_class(main_panel.winfo_class(),'<Button1-Motion>',onB1Motion,add='+')

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Good stuff. Maybe you want to trigger `onB1Motion` at the opening of the window so the frames are aligned?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque to be honest I struglled with that part in the past. The only solution I could imagine is to place the sashes manuelly. But I could update it to this, yes.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am loving both tkinter and its very helpful community!!

Comment: @Atlas435 I have one more problem, when I want to nest this entire window inside another window, all movements affect the nested one as well... Is there a way to fix that ?

Comment: @Kass224 not sure whats the issue, but you could either try edit this `widget.master.winfo_children():` to a specific paned window. Or you bind different events on different paned window and edit this `master.bind_class(main_panel.winfo_class(),'<Button1-Motion>',onB1Motion,add='+')
` code too.